# Get key using javascript callback like Google map api do

Tags: javascript

I have a script.js file which listen various events (click, right click, copy page contact, etc). I add this script.js file in index.php file which is on different server using `<script src="script.js">` tag.

Here, I pass key on that script tag such as, `<script src="script.js?key=134">` to differentiate customers who use script.js file. So different server or customer has different keys.

I want to return that key back from index.php server file to script.js file on each event happen.

How can I return that key to the server to that script.js file on each event happen?

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps have a script tag above this one like the following?

```php
<script>
var CONFIG = {
    key: <?php echo $key; ?>
}
</script>
```

And then you can access `CONFIG.key` in your script.js.

Comment: No I don't have script tag that you ask for. It is simple index.php file where I add my script.js file using html script src tag. This script.js file listen events which happen on index.php file by visitors of that index.php file. Here I want to return key which is stored in script src tag with path of the script.js file like <script src="PATH_OF_THE_FILE/script.js?key=134">. This 134 return back to script.js when any event happen on index.php file.

Comment: So you just want to return from the JS the key value to the server? Is it feasible for you to make a GET or POST request from the JS upon whatever events you are trying to track?

Comment: You are right @Talha. I think I have to use POST request on index.php file on callback function which send key back to server.